# Один пробел подряд, regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь сделать регулярку, которая будет отвечать следующим требованиям:
    **начинается с буквы+ oneormore[начинается с пробела, содержит '_' и '-' и буквы]**

пробовал вот

```
import re

# пытаюсь сделать вот так
pattern = re.compile(r'^\w+(^[ ]?([_-]\w*))*$')
string1 = 'qweqe asd asdasd' # должно вернуть True
string2 = 'asdd dasd-asdasd' # должно вернуть True
string3 = 'dasdasdasda' # True
string4 = 'asd  asdasd' # False

re.search(pattern, string)
```

еще пробовал вот так

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^\w+(^([ ])?([_-]\w*)*([ ])?$)*\w+$')
```

но не срабатывает нормально, с пробелами проблемы возникают, т.к. надо ограничить их одним подряд

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Q3eVoH/1

Comment: Прочитайте описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения] -- надо привести однозначные примеры текстов и что в них найти, а не пытаться словесно описать. Текущих примеров недостаточно. Что такое `oneormore`? Если начинается с пробела, то почему в регулярках он опциональный? И где `[` и `]` в примерах?

Comment: @dIm0n я тоже так попался в мае, вопросу 3 года

Comment: @PotroNik да, но я посмотрел профиль участника и он заходил 4 августа, так что есть шанс на правку

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, так:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^\w+(\s[-_a-zA-Z]+)+$')
```